# Empty List Environment

Tags: macros, lists, enumerate, itemize, description

I created commands for resume fields. This is a simplified example of the desired outcome:
[image]

Currently, I have to create two separate commands to do this, one with `\begin{itemize}` and the other without, otherwise I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

This is because the `\begin{itemize}` environment is empty in the second section.

**Question: Is there a package or a way of using `\begin{itemize}` that allows the environment to be empty? For example:**

```
\begin{itemize}
    % This environment is empty.
\end{itemize}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, 10pt, letterpaper, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\narrowColumn}[0]{0.25\textwidth}
\newcommand{\wideColumn}[0]{0.75\textwidth}
\newcommand{\tabularEndSpacing}[0]{0.375 cm}

% I would like something like this for everything.
\newcommand{\withItemize}[5]{
    \begin{tabular}{r | l}
        \begin{minipage}[c]{\narrowColumn}
            #1
        \end{minipage}
        &
        \begin{minipage}[c]{\wideColumn}
            {\bfseries\scshape#2}, {\itshape#3}\\
            #4
            \begin{itemize}[nosep]
                #5
            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}\\[\tabularEndSpacing]
}

% However, I am forced to create a second command that does not use itemize.
\newcommand{\withoutItemize}[5]{
    \begin{tabular}{r | l}
        \begin{minipage}[c]{\narrowColumn}
            #1
        \end{minipage}
        &
        \begin{minipage}[c]{\wideColumn}
            {\bfseries\scshape#2}, {\itshape#3}\\
            #4
            #5
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}\\[\tabularEndSpacing]
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

% This works fine.
\withItemize{Jun 2013---Present}{Company Name}{Company Location}{Position at Company}{
    \item Comment 1
    \item Comment 2
    \item Comment 3
}

% This does not work.
%\withItemize{Jun 2013---Present}{School Name}{School Location}{Degree}{}

% Using the second command: This works fine.
\withoutItemize{Jun 2013---Present}{School Name}{School Location}{Degree}{}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test whether `#5` is empty. If it is do nothing, otherwise print an `itemize` environment.

```
\newcommand{\myentry}[5]{%
  \begin{tabular}{r | l}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\narrowColumn}
  #1
  \end{minipage}
  &
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\wideColumn}
  \textbf{#2}, \textit{#3}\\
  #4
  \if\relax\detokenize{#5}\relax\else
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    #5
    \end{itemize}
  \fi
  \end{minipage}
  \end{tabular}\\[\tabularEndSpacing]%
}
```

I've removed `\scshape` because fonts normally don't have a boldface small caps variant. Use *one* attribute for emphasis: either bold face or small caps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'll look up `\relax`, `\detokenize` and `\fi`.

Comment: @JDG The `\if\relax\detokenize{...}\relax` sequence of commands is just the safest way for testing whether what's passed (in your case `#5`) is empty or not. Note that typing `{ }` is different from `{}` for the test to succeed.

Comment: Thanks very much. `{ }` vs. `{}` is a very helpful detail.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am using `{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`, which has a boldface small caps that looks quite nice.